# Flow Promise: Cannot return request because Promise [1] is incompatible with <EntityType>

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I have an `entityType` Product and use it to insert the data into `DynamoDB` using `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`

Product.js :

```
export class Product {
    id: string;

    partNumber: string;

    createdAt: Date;
}
```

ProductService.js:

```
export async function addProduct(request: Product): Product {
  try {
    if (request.id === undefined) {
      request.id = uuid.v4();
    }
    const params = {
      TableName: TABLE_NAME,
      Item: request,
    };
    await dynamoDBClient.put(params).promise();
    return request;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(`Error ${err}`);
    throw Error(err);
  }
}
```

When I run the **flow check `./src/`**
I get the following error at **return request**:

Cannot return request because `Promise [1]` is incompatible with

```
Product
 [2]
```

.

Even though the request is of the type Product , it still shows the Promise Error . How do we fix it?

Comment: _"The `async function` declaration defines an asynchronous function, **which returns an [`AsyncFunction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction) object**. An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, **using an implicit [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to return its result**."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))

Comment: @Andreas Yeah . Please suggest if there is any way to handle the Promises to check the return flow type

Comment: Probably just declare `: Promise<Product>` as the return type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async functions always return promises. Even though it looks like you're returning a Product, [the return type of the function should be `Promise<Product>`](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4AUoQCYCuC8A3gFByVwCWeAXHGjFNQHYDmA3BVWCrADkCAWwBGwKAyYsO3KoijAUMYHgCCMBgBFlwbgF8yZUJFhx0AT1YI4AMwLWY1CK3N48OfERgAKRQEcCYCYGT0JiAEpQ3GFqNGAAHjDvAD44cnlFGAIoVwCgpgMgA).